# Regular expression /(ab)?use/: Is a more complex expression worth it?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm writing a simple Perl script that translates assembly instruction strings to 32-bit binary code.

I decided to handle translation grouping instruction by type (`ADD` and `SUB` are R-Type instructions and so on...) so in my code I'm doing something like this:

```
my $bin = &r_type($instruction) if $instruction =~ /^(?:add|s(?:ub|lt|gt))\s/;
```

because I want to handle `add`, `sub`, `slt` and `sgt` in the same way.

I realized however that maybe using that regular expression could be an 'overkill' for the task I'm supposed to do... could the pattern

```
/^(?:add|sub|slt|sgt)\s/
```

represent a better use of regular expressions in this case?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In this case, listing the opcodes is much clearer for reading.  Use the alternations.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unless you are using a perl older than 5.10, the simple alternation will perform better anyway (see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Trie-optimisation-of-literal-string-alternations)), so there is no reason to try to optimize it.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of placing the mnemonics buried inside regular expressions, build a dispatch table using a hash. It will be at least equally faster and your code far easier to follow:

```
my %emitter = (add => \&r_type,
               sub => \&r_type,
               slt => \&r_type,
               sgt => \&r_type,
               ...);

if ($instruction =~ /^(\S+)/) {
    my $emitter = $emitter{$1} // die "bad instruction $instruction";
    $emitter->($1, $istruction);
}
else {
    # error?...
}
```

Comment: Very nice approach! Thank you for the advice :)

Answer (score 5):

I like [salva's dispatch table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614158/regular-expression-abuse-is-a-more-complex-expression-worth-it/6615427#6615427) (I show a lot of that in *Mastering Perl*), but I'll answer another aspect of the question in case you need that answer for a different problem someday.

When you want to build some alternations, some of which might be nested, you can use something like [Regexp::Trie](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Trie) to build the alternation for you so you don't look at the ugly regex syntax:

```
use Regexp::Trie;
my $rt = Regexp::Trie->new;

foreach ( qw/add sub slt sgt/ ) {
    $rt->add($_);
    }

print $rt->regexp, "\n";
```

That gives you:

```
 (?-xism:(?:add|s(?:gt|lt|ub)))
```

This way, you list the opcodes like Jonathan suggested, but also get the alternation. As ysth noted, you might get this for free with Perl now anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll keep it in mind! (... and found my summer reading... ;) )

Answer (score 4):

Your second version is simpler, more readable, and more maintainable. The performance difference will depend on the regex implementation, but I suspect the nested version will run slower due to its increased complexity.

Yes it's overkill.